# send json stream to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have problem in sending json string to an asp.net page, i want to send long stream bs just now i'm trying with short one. i don't know if this is the right way, but i don't know another one.
 it doesn't arrive in json format ! 
this in client code in c#:

```
List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();
                                    Employee eo = new Employee();
                                    eo = new Employee();
                                    eo.Name = "Santosh";
                                    eo.Age = 24;
                                    eList.Add(eo);

                                    queryString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

                                    if (flagFirstTime==0)
                                    {
                                        onlineApp = settings.onlinURL + @"/Admin/HR/Attendance_UpdateData.ashx?" + queryString;//here the json string 
                                        urlAdress = onlineApp;
                                        flagFirstTime = 1;
                                    }


                                    Uri url = new Uri(urlAdress);
                                    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                                    webReq.Method = "Get";
```

and in asp.net page,:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    { 
        Teachers_Att_Data teacherAttDataNew; 

        try 
        { 

            var jsonString = String.Empty; 

            var stream = context.Request.InputStream; 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length]; 
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer); 


            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
            context.Response.Write("updated"); 

        }  
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
                  context.Response.Write("f"); 
        } 


    }
```

Comment: Sending your JSON as a query string is almost bound to cause you length problems in the long run. Set it as your request body. Furthermore, use a `StreamReader` to read the body instead of mocking up your own way. `new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();`

Comment: In fact, it looks like you aren't even setting your query string parameters in the right way. It *should* be in key/value pairs, and it looks like you just put everything directly on without a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Request.Url.Query` to read the string as you send it, the way I see it. So your handler must be like:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    { 
        Teachers_Att_Data teacherAttDataNew; 

        try 
        { 
            string xml = context.Request.Url.Query.ToString();

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
            context.Response.Write("updated");     
        }  
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
                  context.Response.Write("f"); 
        } 
    }
```

Please note, I am not sure if the rest work, or what your logic is on your program, but this is the way to read the url parameters.

Also use `Server.URLEncode` when you place the string on url as:

```
onlineApp = settings.onlinURL 
     + @"/Admin/HR/Attendance_UpdateData.ashx?" + Server.URLEncode(queryString);
```